# Safari Issue with css transform

Tags: css, safari

I have a wordpress site which i am helping a friend out with

https://capturingscotland.com/galleries

When hovering over the gallery images it shows a transparent red image with a more button. It works fine in chrome, IE, Firefox but when i have tried it on iphones and Ipads with safari it dosent seem to work. Below is the CSS classes used. porto-item is the gallery item

```
.porto .porto-item:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: .2;
}
.porto .porto-item:hover .porto-info {
  opacity: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}
.porto .porto-item:hover .title {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 white;
}
.porto .porto-item:hover .categories {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 white;
}
.porto .porto-item:hover .more {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it so that whenever the item is touched the hover appears (like if scrolling) then you can add: `cursor: pointer;` to the element you wish the hover to appear on. Without this iOS only styles `:hover` events on links.

Comment: Excellent thanks although odd that it works on android and windows phones and tablets?

Comment: it's a good point @GraemeBaillie. I've updated my answer to reflect the `cursor: pointer` trick, iOS can have hover effects similar to touch Android but only on links or anything with the style `cursor: pointer`.

Comment: Excellent need to find an iphone to test it now :)

Comment: No worries. If you're developing on a mac you can use the developer simulator (type `open /applications/xcode.app/contents/developer/applications/simulator.app` into terminal). You can then use Safari to inspect element. If not though then finding an iphone is the next best bet! If it does work for you feel free to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry still not working, tried the focus and putting cursor pointer as the style on the outer divs and inner divs as well. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Hmm strange. Just to be clear, what is the exact circumstances the style appears on Android and not on iOS? Is it when you click the item (to navigate to it) or when you scroll up and down and in doing so your finger hits the `porto-item` with which you want to trigger the hover?

Comment: When you click on the item with your finger or click the mouse it turns red from showing an image. If you look at the link in the original description you will see the behaviour.